# What does each statistic do in Dragon Quest XI?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

Simple question. Some stats are easy to figure out, like attack and defense, but others are more complex.

- Like what is the difference between magical might and mending?
- What are the uses of Deftness and Charm in combat situations?

So is there a list of what stats do what in Dragon Quest XI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stat effects can be viewed in the Traveller's tips menu section, under:

Menu > Misc. > Traveller's Tips > Battle > All About Attributes

There are also some pretty good guides online that define what each statistic does and what abilities/effects it alters (e.g. https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/235919-dragon-quest-xi-echoes-of-an-elusive-age/faqs/76680/stats-and-their-functions). To simplify it greatly, each stat TYPICALLY has one main function:

Strength: physical damage
Magical Might: magic damage/status efficiency
Magical Mending: healing/revival efficiency
Deftness: critical rate chance for physical & magic
Resilience: Defense
Agility: Turn order & evasion
Charm: Beguilement chance